# onclick make multiple div's selectable ( and submit values from those divs on form submit )

Tags: jquery, forms, onclick, submit

What would be a good approach to make a set of square divs clickable, toggle a class on them to indicate they are (addClass) selected. 
then on form submit only submit the values of those divs? Perhaps Using a hidden field for each div with a value. Only the hidden values of the selected square divs should be submitted.

I have search for a solution except the addClass indication a div is clicked I have no clue on how to approach this, any thoughts on a good way to this? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet is to use ajax for this and reload page on succes callback. But you can do it without ajax (in theory as i never test it before)

```
$('form input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
        $('div:not(.mySelectedClass) input').removeAttr('name');
        $('form').submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```